# Prevent GridView OnRowCommand to execute for specific gridview column Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView defined like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_Messages" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  PageSize="5" CellPadding="4" AllowPaging="true" Width=100% AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="GridView_Messages_Sorting"
                         ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" OnRowDataBound="GridView_Messages_OnRowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView_Messages_PageIndexChanged" OnRowCommand="GridView_Messages_OnRowCommand" EmptyDataText="<%$ Resources:Localization, NoMsg %>">
                        <%--CssClass="Grid" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"--%>
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="75" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="allchk" runat="server" />
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="check" Text="" TextAlign="Right" AutoPostBack="false" Checked="false"  runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="GridView_Messages_CheckedChanged"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MessageID" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="GridView_Messages_lblMessageID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MessageID") %>'/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Localization, Title2 %>" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" SortExpression="it.Title">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="GridView_Messages_lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="GridView_Messages_lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description")%>'/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FromUserID" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="GridView_Messages_lblFromUserID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FromUserID")%>'/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Localization, From %>" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" SortExpression="it.UserName">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="GridView_Messages_lblFromUserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName")%>'/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Notes" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="GridView_Messages_lblNotes" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Notes") %>'/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Localization, IsRead %>" Visible="false" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" SortExpression="it.IsRead">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="GridView_Messages_lblIsRead" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IsRead") %>'/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Localization, TimeSent %>" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" SortExpression="it.SentDateTime">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="GridView_Messages_lblDateTime" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SentDateTime") %>'/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Msg_lnkBtnClk" runat="server" CommandName="SingleClick" Text="click"
                                        Visible="true" CssClass="hidden"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="Msg_lnkBtnDblClk" runat="server" CommandName="DoubleClick" Text="dblClick"
                                        Visible="true" CssClass="hidden"/>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C7B88D" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

I don't want my OnRowCommand to execute for the first column of my GridView. Actually I don't want my event to fire when some of my checkboxes is clicked. How to determine if I have clicked on a checkbox or I have clicked somewhere else in a gridview? In WPF I could use e.OriginalSource property but here this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/):
If you haven't already added JQuery to your page, add this tag to your page's head section:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And this is the actual code. Add this after the link to JQuery, in the .aspx page's `head` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
          $('#<%= GridView_Messages.ClientID %> input[type="checkbox"]')
          .click(function(event){
              event.stopPropagation();
              event.preventDefault();
          })
      });
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Do I need somehow to define type of event which I'm trying to stop? I don't completely understand how is this working.

Comment: You will have to put this code in your .aspx file bcoz it uses asp.net server tag. What error do you get in the console?

Comment: How do I call this function in aspx file? And where exactly do I need to put it?